# Error: Don't know how to make

Tags: c, makefile

I have been given a makefile which I modified into this:

```
############################################
# Makefile using OCI (Oracle Call Interface)
# D. LaRue  -  May, 2001
############################################

ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oratcp11/product/11.2.0/client11R2_32bits
CC=/opt/SUNWspro/SUNWspro12/sparc/SUNWspro/bin/cc
COMMON_SRC=../common
BNS_INCLUDE=../include
LIBHOME=$(ORACLE_HOME)/lib/
RDBMSLIB=$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/lib/
WSSCOMMON_LIB=/vobs/wssCommon/lib_32
TARGET_DIR=.

LLIBCRYPTO  =-lbnscrypto
LSOLCRYPTO  =-lcryptoutil -lpkcs11
WSSLIBS     =-lwssmbx -ldes
LIBRDBMS_CLT    =-lclient11 -lvsn11 -lcommon11 -lgeneric11 -lmm
LLIBCLNTSH      =-lclntsh -ldl 
CORELIBS        =-lcore11 -lnls11 
LDLIBS          =-lnsl -lsocket -lgen -lm
EXSYSLIBS       =-R $(ORACLE_HOME)/lib

STATICTTLIBS    =$(LLIBRDBMS_CLT) $(CORELIBS) $(WSSLIBS) $(LLIBCRYPTO)
OCISHAREDLIBS   =$(LLIBCLNTSH) $(LDLIBS) -Bstatic $(STATICTTLIBS) -Bdynamic $(LSOLCRYPTO)

LDFLAGS     =-L$(ORACLE_HOME)/lib -L$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/lib -L$(WSSCOMMON_LIB) -L../lib_32

INCLUDE     =-I$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/demo -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/public -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/plsql/public -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/network/public -I$(COMMON_SRC) -I$(BNS_INCLUDE) -I. 

CFLAGS      =$(INCLUDE) $(LDFLAGS) -g -Xt

BESSOBJS=bessToWss.o

COMMONLIST=$(COMMON_SRC)/oracle.c \
           $(COMMON_SRC)/logger.c 

INTFOBJS=$(BESSOBJS) $(COMMONLIST)

ALL:    $(TARGET_DIR)/bessToWss

$(TARGET_DIR)/bessToWss: $(INTFOBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INTFOBJS) $(OCISHAREDLIBS) -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) *.o
```

When I run the file I get an error

```
". Stop.e: Error:  Don't know how to make "bessToWss
```

Any idea what is wrong? I run this on some unix machine via a script. The script calls make after sets some paths or some other settings. As you can see I'm not sure how it's called.

Thanks :)

Comment: have you got spaces instead of tabs  at the start of `    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INTFOBJS) $(OCISHAREDLIBS) -o $@` make needs tabs at the start of commands

Comment: Spaces vs tabs gives a different error, I believe.

Comment: @gbulmer I have a tab there. tx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message looks peculiar — do you have CRLF line endings in the makefile?

`". Stop.e: Error:  Don't know how to make "bessToWss`

That could be:

`/bin/make: Error:  Don't know how to make "bessToWss`<kbd>CR</kbd>`". Stop.`

where the <kbd>CR</kbd> is the carriage return moving the print position back to the start of the line.

Did you create the makefile, or edit it, on a Windows machine?  Did you FTP or copy it without using a text mode transfer, so the CRLF line-endings were preserved?

If so, get rid of the carriage returns.  Edit the file on Unix with `vim` and do `:set fileformat=unix` and save again.

Under this hypothesis, `make` is trying to build a program whose name includes a CR (carriage return) in the name and you've not given it a rule for doing that.

Comment: I shall try. I am editing w vim in windows, so yea it's windows format... tx